# Merging Dataframes to update cells with most recent timestamp

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset stored in a dataframe that I need to periodically update from a REST API, but the catch is I only want to update specific cells where the timestamps are more recent when I pull from the REST API.

To illustrate I have the following dataframe:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'item': ['apple', 'orange', 'bananna'], 
               'A': ['2021-03-01', np.nan, '2021-08-01'], 
               'B': ['2021-03-01', '2020-03-16', '2021-07-15'],
               'C': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]}) 
df1
     item    A          B           C
---------------------------------------
0    apple   2021-03-01 2021-03-01  NaN
1    orange  NaN        2020-03-16  NaN
2    bananna 2021-08-01 2021-07-15  NaN
```

Then I pull an updated list from the API that looks like this:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'item': ['apple', 'orange', 'bananna', 'watermelon'], 
               'A': ['2021-03-09', '2021-03-09', np.nan, '2021-03-09'], 
               'B': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, '2021-03-09'],
               'C': ['2021-03-09', '2021-03-09', np.nan, '2021-03-09']})
df2
    item       A          B          C
-----------------------------------------------
0   apple      2021-03-09 NaN        2021-03-09
1   orange     2021-03-09 NaN        2021-03-09
2   bananna    NaN        NaN        NaN
3   watermelon 2021-03-09 2021-03-09 2021-03-09
```

How do I merge those so that each cell under A, B, & C retain the most recent timestamp to get a result that looks like this?

```
    item       A          B          C
-----------------------------------------------
0   apple      2021-03-09 2021-03-01 2021-03-09
1   orange     2021-03-09 2020-03-16 2021-03-09
2   bananna    2021-08-01 2021-07-15 NaN
3   watermelon 2021-03-09 2021-03-09 2021-03-09
```

Normally if I only had 1 column of timestamps I would do the following:

```
tmpDF1 = df1[["item", 'A']]
tmpDF2 = df2[["item", 'A']]
tmpDF1 = tmpDF1.append(tmpDF2, sort=False, ignore_index=True)
tmpDF1 = tmpDF1.sort_values(by='A', ascending=False, ignore_index=True)
tmpDF1 = tmpDF1.drop_duplicates(subset=['item'],keep='first')
```

So with 1 timtestamp columns I'd just append, sort, drop dupes with keep first and I'm all good.  However with multiple timestamp fields I can't figure out how to update each cell.

Is this possible or do I need to subset this all into 3 different dataframes, append, sort & drop dupes and then mrege them back together into 1 dataframe?  Or is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `concat` then `groupby().max()`:

```
pd.concat([df2,df1]).groupby('item',as_index=False,sort=False).max()
```

Output

```
         item          A          B          C
0       apple 2021-03-09 2021-03-01 2021-03-09
1      orange 2021-03-09 2020-03-16 2021-03-09
2     bananna 2021-08-01 2021-07-15        NaT
3  watermelon 2021-03-09 2021-03-09 2021-03-09
```

Comment: First `A, B, C` columns need to be converted to `datetime`, otherwise it would throw an error, doesn't it?

Comment: @ashkangh `first` doesn't care about datatype, so no.

Comment: sorry, bad example on my part.  The real data is a datetime value.   That was just a quick and dirty sample DF to illustrate what I was trying to do.

Comment: @user3246693 It's OK. Like I said, the code should work for any type of data. You just need to make sure that your data types are consistent between `df2` and `df1`.

Comment: Thank you for that, my only question now is I don't understand why that works?  I thought .first grabbed the first row with the most recent timestamp(or highest value is it's note datetime).  Since there's no sorting in your solution how is that determining the most recent timestamp for each column?

Comment: Oh, if you mean get the most recent time, then use `max` instead of `first`. Hope that `max` is self-explained :-). Apology that I didn't catch the that part.

Comment: Max makes sense, but that appears to only be referencing column "A".  I need to merge the two dataframes and always get the most recent timestamp in each of the columns.  Using max is giving me NaN for B & C for Apple, Orange, and Banana, but column A is updating correctly.  How do I get the max across multiple columns like that?  Or do I need to subset it 3 times, run a max and then combine the subsets back into 1 on the item?

Comment: @user3246693 Are you sure? I just ran the example with `datetime` type and works as expected.

Comment: doh!!!  I converted my sample to datetime but just realized I only converted column A.  Converted all 3 and it's working as expected.  Thank you!